# racket: (my-filter p lst) function with lambda and foldr

Tags: list, lambda, racket

I am trying to implement a function (my-filter p lst) by using lambda, map and foldr.

What I have so far is:

```
(define (my-filter1 p lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) empty]
        [(p (first lst))
         (cons (first lst) (my-filter1 p (rest lst)))]
        [else (my-filter1 p (rest lst))]))
```

It works fine, but I how can I change the code to one using lambda, map and foldr?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we need to see how `foldr` works.

```
  (foldr k e '(1 2 3))
= (k 1 (k 2 (k 3 e)))
```

It helps to think of `k` as `cons` and of `e` as `empty`.
For example:

```
  (foldr cons empty '(1 2 3))
= (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 empty)))
= (list 1 2 3)
```

To make a filter we need to use a "cons" that only 
prepends the element if the element, if the predicate is fulfilled.

```
(define (kons x xs)
  (if (p x)           ; where p is the predicate
      (cons x xs)
      xs))
```

Given this custom "cons" function we can write filter as

```
 (foldr kons empty '(1 2 3))
```

A complete example:

```
#lang racket

(define p odd?)

(define (kons x xs)
  (if (p x)
      (cons x xs)
      xs))

(foldr kons empty '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
```

The result is:

```
 '(1 3 5)
```

To turn this into a filter function use this template:

```
(define (my-filter p xs)
   (define (kons x xs) ...)
   (foldr ...))
```